# Unable to correctly format and boot certain USB drives

Tags: boot, usb-drive, format

I've just bought a small laptop, with no optical drive at all, and I would like to install an OS (in this case Crunchbang) on it. I couldn't have been create a bootable drive, on my Ubuntu desktop, where I'm writing from now. The laptop can boot from USB, it has been tried in the shop with a Win8. I've also managed to recognize other drives with it, but those I don't want to turn into a bootable drive, I have already wasted two of them, as it seems I can not format it properly. All of them I tried to install my .iso file, has gone unusable.

I don't really know what to do, my desire is simple. I only want to format/repair one of my corrupted drives and install the os with it to the laptop.

The laptop is: **Lenovo Thinkpad X61**
My USB drive: **Kingston 4GB**

I have already tried the Ubuntu Startup Disc Creator, it's escaped with an error.
I have tried to follow along some tutorials and format it from terminal, no use.
I have installed and worked on it with GParted and UNetbootin, no use.

I must have been doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to install an operating system via USB. 
I'm not sure, but it looked like to me the BIOS was too old for recognizing my 4Gig drives, fortunately it recognized 2 of my 1Gig drives, when I tried it.

I was able to make a bootable one with UNetbootin. Neither the Ubuntu system, or my softwares had problems. It is only *the BIOS in old computers that might had something* to do with it.

I hope my answer can help someone dealing with the same or similar.